# Maior quantidade de aparições de um elemento em um array de objetos - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array, algoritmo, typescript

Olá, 
tenho um array de notícias(objetos)

```
lista: Array<Noticia> = [];
```

Desse array preciso descobrir o autor que mais publicou noticias. 
Uma noticia tem:

*ID | Título | Tags |* **Autor** *| Conteúdo*.

Minha ideia inicial foi:

```
public totalPublicacoes(){
 var autorM = '';
 var autor = this.lista[0].autor;
 var qtM = 0;
 var qt = 0;
 for(let i=0; i<this.lista.length; i++){       
   if(autor == this.lista[i].autor){
     qt ++;
     if(qt > qtM){
       qtM = qt;
       autorM = this.lista[i].autor;
     }
   }
 }
 console.log(autorM);}
```

Com isso minha ideia inicial foi pegar o autor do primeiro objeto do array

verificar se ele era igual ao próximo elemento autor do array

caso sim eu somava a qt de vezes que ele apareceu

caso a qt atual fosse maior que a quantidade maior de aparições

eu atualizava o valor da maior aparição

e guardava o nome do autor que em tese mais publicou.

Porém não está funcionando, podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia Gabriel tenta assim:

```
seuarraydenoticias.reduce(function (autores, autor) { 
  if (autor.Autor in autores) {
    autores[autor.Autor]++;
  }
  else {
    autores[autor.Autor] = 1;
  }

  return autores;
}, {});
```

else vai retornar um novo array com o nome do autor e a quantidade.

Espero ter ajudado amigo.

Comment: Nossa deu certo! muito obrigado! só uma duvida, o tipo desse autores é obj certo? sendo assim terei que quebra-ló para poder comparar os valores certo?

Comment: Na verdade estou tentando agora separar esses valores para poder comparar e dizer quem publicou, mas está difícil uma vez que não sei qual o nome do valor que diz sobre a contagem de publicações..

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal consegui resolver, caso alguém algum dia passe pela mesma situação:

```
public maisPublicou() {
const frequency = this.lista
  .map(({ autor }) => autor)
  .reduce((autores, autor) => {
    const count = autores[autor] || 0;
    autores[autor] = count + 1;
    return autores;
  }, {});
var qt = 0;
var autorM = '';
for (var key in frequency) {
  if (frequency[key] > qt) {
    qt = frequency[key];
    autorM = key;
  }
}
return autorM;}
```